Create site not working for Domain Based in DNN
I'm trying to create a site using Add New Site, in the DNN website. Whenever I create a Domain based site this page shows below.

I've tried various aliases but none work
When using Directory Based this works which is marked red below.

Also entries are going smoothly as you can see below in the DB.

Is my installation not ok or is there some issue with DNN 09.13.04. I'm not sure with that.
Update 1:

It shows the website working with IIS page now I want to edit it using DNN platform how can I do that? Like the www.dnndev.me can be edited.

If you are going to create a domain-based site, you will need to make sure you have the domain name registered with nameservers and DNS records pointing to the IP Address where you have DNN running.
If you are trying to "fake" a domain, not actually registering it but use DNN as if it were, you need to modify your HOSTS file to point that domain name to your local IP Address, example add the following two lines to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

127.0.0.1 www.test-dang2.com
127.0.0.1 test-dang2.com

Update:
After you add the HOSTS entry, you then need to go into IIS and add the domain to the website in IIS. You do this through the SITE BINDINGS

I've added in the question now I want to edit using the editor of DNN the website like www.dnndev.me but it shows like an IIS page which is pointed to 127.0.0.1, but no editor can be seen as i look at it?

@namco updated my answer, you need to tell IIS where to send that traffic, it's being intercepted by the default site now

Thanks @Chris I've right click the website(DNN mine is myDNNsite) and clicked edit bindings to which I've added the URL which is registered in the hosts file. It is working great now
